# how to add information to a row and csv with powershell?

Tags: powershell, csv, automation

i have csv file with 3 columns SID, SamAccount name, ENABLED.
i also have folder containing files that called in a combination of "UVHD-"+SID.
i try to update the csv file with Length, LastWriteTime
so it will be like this for example:

```
SID     SAMAccountName     Enabled      Length      LastWriteTime
S-...   FelixR             False        205520896   02/02/2021  9:13:40
```

i tried many things and all failed
this is the best i could get:

```
Import-Csv $path\SID-ListTEST2.csv | select -ExpandProperty SID | ForEach-Object { Get-Childitem –Path $path\"UVHD-"$_.vhdx | Export-Csv $path\SID-ListTEST2.csv -Append | where $_   }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [calculated properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Calculated_Properties):

```
(
  Import-Csv $path\SID-ListTEST2.csv | 
    Select-Object *, 
                  @{ 
                    Name='LastWriteTime';
                    Expression={ (Get-Item "$path\UVHD-$($_.SID).vhdx").LastWriteTime } 
                  }
) | # Export-Csv -NoTypeInformation -Encoding utf8 $path\SID-ListTEST2.csv
```

<sup>Outputs to the *display*; remove the `#` from the last line to export to a CSV file instead.

Note the `(...)` around the pipeline, which ensures that all output is collected *up front*, which is the prerequisite for saving the results *back to the original input file*.  Note that the original character encoding isn't necessarily preserved - use `-Encoding` to specify the desired one.</sup>

This adds *one* additional property, `LastWriteTime`; construct the other ones analogously.

For improved performance, you could *cache* the result of the `Get-Item` call, so that it doesn't have to be repeated in every calculated property: In the simplest case, use `($script:file = Get-Item ...)` in the *first* calculated property, which you can then reuse as `$script:file` (or just `$file`) in the subsequent ones. Note that the `$script:` scope modifier is necessary, because the script blocks of calculated properties run in *child* scopes.<sup>[1]</sup>

Note that if no matching file exists, the `Get-Item` call fails *silently* and defaults to `$null`.

---

<sup>[1] Therefore, the more robust - but more cumbersome - approach would be to use `Set-Variable -Scope 1 file (Get-Item ...)` instead of `$script:file = Get-Item ...`, to ensure that the variable is created in the immediate parent scope, whatever it happens to be.</sup>